# Reporting Services 2005 Report with Disclaimers page after each section

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services

Details:

I am using Reporting Services 2005 in a C# Application with Visual Studio 2008 to generate reports based on a SQL Server 2005 database.  The application views the report locally using the .net report viewer and no report server is used.  There is a page break in the report after each person.  I am currently using just one report table for the .rdlc file to generate the report.

Question:

My client wants to put a disclaimers page after the grouping has ended for each person listed on the report.  The client wants to be able to adjust the disclaimer page on the fly through the user interface, before running the report.  Please offer suggestions on how I can accomplish this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to create another report for the sole purpose of rendering the Disclaimer content. The Disclaimer report can then be embedded (via a subreport: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348.aspx) into your existing reports thereby allowing you to dynamically modify the content of the Disclaimer separately.

You could store the actual Disclaimer content within a SQL Server Database table and update it via any number of the typical simple standard .NET controls that are at your disposal.

This has the advantage of no character restrictions as per the prior recommendation.

Comment: You rock.  This is the solution that worked best for me.  Simon Wilson also had a good answer, but for my particular situation this was the best fit.  Despite the votes, I am designating this "the" solution.  I needed an entire page of disclaimers and this worked.

Comment: @Jeremy Hess: Excellent news! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean they want to adjust it on the fly PRIOR to executing the report or after? 
If before, could you not use a parameter, with the disclaimer template as the default value and submit it to the report when they are done? You could then put the parameter in the group footer.
If after then...good luck :) The report is rendered into whatever format chosen. If you are retrieving the report in html and have the rendered file perhaps custom parsing could be done but seems a bit naff. Been a while with SRS, hopefully the param could work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I meant on the fly before the report is run, so that makes it a little easier.  I had trouble passing a parameter to the report footer.  Are you 100% sure this is possible. Thanks, Jeremy

Comment: Oh, absolutely. Bear in mind that the max url IE can handle is is 2083 chars, which applies to both POST and GET requests.
Create a Report Parameter, Disclaimer, set the default value and set Group Footer cell’s value to =Parameters!Disclaimer.Value (Just tried it myself to be sure as it has been so long)
If you think the disclaimer could be too long to pass around build it with tokens and have the users enter the data that changes as params and set the footer to the template after replacing the tokens

Comment: By the exclamation points can I assume it worked? :) Or were you really excited to run off and try it?

Comment: I just appreciated the help.  I have another solution which I discovered on my own.  I am still deciding which is best.  I gave you an up vote, but I want to wait for more answers before choosing "the" solution.  That being said, thanks for taking time to help me with this.